# Expected value of sum of independent variables squared

Tags: expected-value, independence

Hi can someone tell me if I can decompose the following:
x any y are statistically independent and have zero mean.

$E((x + y)^2) = E(x^2) + E(y^2)$

I tried with setting into the definition of the expected value:

$\sum_{x}\sum_{y}(x^2 + 2xy + y^2) P(X = x, Y = y)$

$\sum_{x}\sum_{y}x^2 P(X = x, Y = y) + \sum_{x}\sum_{y} 2xy P(X = x, Y = y) + \sum_{y}\sum_{x} y^2 P(X = x, Y = y)$

$\sum_{x}x^2 P(X = x) + 2\sum_{y}\sum_{x}xy P(X = x, Y = y) + \sum_{y} y^2 P(Y = y) $

$E(x^2) + 2 E(xy) + E(y^2)$

I come to the statement above, but I think it is wrong I need the first statement for a proof and I can't image how I can do if the first statement is wrong.

Comment: First of all (x+y)$^2$ = x$^2$ +2xy + y$^2$. So what is E(xy)?. It is not necessarily 0 without other assumptions.

Comment: x and y are independent, but can I then say they are zero?

Comment: So it could be 0 if x and y are independent and E(x)=0 or E(y)=0 or both. But you need some condition like this. You have said nothing about whether or not x and y are correlated and what there expectations are.

Comment: Ah sorry they have zero mean, ok so it gets zero?

Comment: Yes because if they are independent E(xy)=E(x) E(y)=0 since E(x)=E(y)=0.

Comment: Ok but then all above would be zero? Because E(x^2) = E(x)E(x) = 0 and E(y^2) = E(y)E(y) = 0

Comment: No x is not independent of x and x$^2$ will only be positive or 0. for its expectation to be 0 it would have to be that x is identically 0..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$. So,

\begin{align*}
E((X+Y)^2) & = E(X^2 +2XY + Y^2)\\
& = E(X^2) +2 E(XY) +E(Y^2)\\
& = E(X^2) +2 E(X)E(Y) +E(Y^2)\\
& = E(X^2) +2 (0) +E(Y^2)\\
& = E(X^2)+E(Y^2)\,.
\end{align*}

Regarding your comment

> Ok but then all above would be zero? Because $E(X^2) = E(X)E(X) = 0$ and
>   $E(X^2) = E(X)E(X) = 0$

This isn't true because that decomposition is possible if two random variables are independent. Since $X$ isn't independent of $X$, $E(X^2) \ne E(X)E(X)$.

Comment: Ok, that means if E(X) = 0 it doesn't imply that E(X^2) = 0 ?

Comment: @flow Exactly. To give you some intuition, suppose $X$ takes values uniformly between -1 and 1. Then $X$ has mean 0. But $X^2$ (which just squares the values of $X$) takes value between 0 and 1, and thus cannot have mean 0.

Comment: Ok thanks just for clearness, is then E(x^2)E(y^2) = 0?

Comment: @flow No, for the same reason. $E(X^2Y^2) = E(X^2)E(Y^2)$ by independence, but the individual expectations are not going to be zero.